# Need a FFT for an near infinite set of data points

Tags: c, transform, fft

I need to perform a Fourier transform on a long stream of data. I made a DFT .c file that works fine, the downside is of course the speed. It is slow AF.

I am looking for a way to perform the FFT on a long stream of data.
All the FFT libs require an array of max 1024, 2048 or some even 4096 data points.

I get the data from an ADC that runs around 128000 Hz and I need to measure data between 1 and 10 seconds. This means an array from 128 000 to 1 280 000 samples. In my code I check the frequencies 0 till 2000. It took around 400 core ticks for one sin+cos calculation. The core runs at 480 Mhz, so it costs around 1 us.

This means 2000 frequencies * 128 000 samples * 1 us = +/- 256 seconds(4 min) of analysis per 1 second of data.

And when 10 secs are used, it would cost 40 mins.

Does anyone know a faster way or a FFT solution that supports a near "infinite" data array?

Comment: Do you really need the precision that comes from computing with so many samples? You can always just compute the FFT on smaller segments of your data.

Comment: FFTs are efficient because they use power-of-two size inputs. Having arbitrary-size data breaks this a bit. As a side note, 128 000 samples is very far from near-infinite. I'd suggest reading into how FFTs and Fourier transforms in general work.

Comment: If you are doing block FT the low-freq components will be limited by the block size. There is no FFT algorithm working on streamed data. You could look into Sparse Fourier Transform (SFT) instead, which has been designed specifically for that. Info on the lowe freqs will only be available once the full dataset in acquired.

Comment: Why do you need to measure for that long? If you actually need the low frequency components, decimate your samples. If not, just limit your block size.

Comment: Your claim that one sin+cos calculation costs 400 ticks is plausible, but 400 ticks is not 1 ns (nanosecond) on a 480 MHz processor — each tick is about 2 ns.  So, it's wrong by three orders of magnitude — it would be about 1 µs (microsecond).  Interestingly, the calculation 2k * 128k * 1 µs _is_ about 256 seconds.  So, you probably simply (mis)used ns where you mean µs (or 'us' if you don't have easy access to Greek characters).

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes i do need that precision. We intend to set noise onto it and perform a Fourier transform. We also care about the phase shift. So, we want to be able to detect up to a 10KHz, therefore we do need the prececion.

Comment: @ThomasJager yes, 128 000 is not near-infinite, i know. But when i looked around at most FFT libs, but the input has the size of 2N, with a max of 4096, maybe some have 16384 points. Wich they almost never do (I never found one). So, if the max set number of variables for all FFTs are to little, I am looking for a way to theoretically proccess infinit data. Also, the measuring time is not a set length. It might change and might become way more than 10 secs.
I do know about the normal Fourier, but not yes much about the FFT, still learning, thats why i asked for a solution for a large data set

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes, i did ment 1us, i always switch the us and ns up. I edited it now. thnx

Comment: @norok2 Thanks, i will look into the SFT

Comment: I don’t believe any of this. I don’t believe you need to do a 100k-point FFT, and I don’t believe it’s hard to find an implementation that can do it. Note that if you only read the first 2000 elements from the output, then you only need to do a 2000-point FFT. If you are worried about the noise, you can average over many 2000-point FFTs in your sample window.

Comment: You only need 10KHz. You can decimate to 25.6 KHz easily, which should give you more than enough breathing room.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Hmm, i am really not an expert. But now, i do think you are right. I only need the Hz I want to measure times 2 a 3 times. I thought i needed it in order to measure the phase correctly, but the Fourier doesn't care about high data rates. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If your calculation involved floating points, avoid double precision if you doesn't need that kind of guaranteed floating point precision.

If your ADC resolution is not that high (says less than 16 bits), you can consider to use fixed point arithmetic. This can help to reduce computation time especially if your machine does not support hardware floating point calculation. please refer: [Q number format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q_(number_format))

If you are using ARM base controller, you may want to check out this:
http://www.keil.com/pack/doc/CMSIS/DSP/html/index.html